# DB2 UNION ALL brings down performance of query

Tags: sql, db2, query-optimization, database-performance

I am running query similar to below.

```
Query 1
UNION ALL
Query 2
```

Query 1 alone takes about 20 seconds and returns about 1000 rows.
Query 2 alone takes about 20 seconds and returns about 4000 rows.
However when run with UNION ALL, it takes more than 10 minutes.

I do not expect UNION ALL to be expensive as it does not even have to remove duplicates, just merge results.

When I look at access plan, for whole query vs just query 1/2, same access plan is getting generated for query 1/2 when run individually vs in UNION ALL.

Nothing looks unusual with the cost, however I see 'Estimated number of rows' for query 1 and query 2 are nowhere close to real numbers. It shows more than 60,000,000 for each query, where as you can see query 1 just returns 1000 and 2 returns 4000. Can this lead to bad UNION ALL performance ?

Have an interesting update -
Both queries, which work individually fine, look similar to below

```
SELECT col1, CASE WHEN col2=1 THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END, SUM(col3)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY col1, 
         col2, /*This was not part of original query, I added it in order to be able to remove line below*/
        CASE WHEN col2=1 THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END
```

If I remove, 'CASE WHEN col2=1 THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END' from GROUP BY in both queries, they start performing as poorly as UNION ALL query. Again, nothing looks wrong in comparison of access plans with and without CASE in group by.

Comment: This question is not about programming , but is better suited for a DBA group like dha.stackexchange.com . If you have enough skill to analyse an access plan, perhaps you also have the skill to monitor runtime performance and compare actuals to estimates,  and ensure statistics are adequate, and ensure statistical-views are appropriate.

Comment: Can you post the execution plan?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the size of each result set (60 million records) is large enough such that perhaps the full union cannot be stored in memory at one time.  If so, then DB2 would be forced to page out a portion of the result set to disk.  Disk reading and writing can be orders of magnitude slower than doing the same operations in memory.

Comment: That makes sense if at least one of the subqueries is materialized. If both are pipelined the whole query should be fast anyway.